# Batch RPG : Fight Loop Broken

Tags: batch-file, variables

So, couple of problems I'm having.

1. When the TutorialFight runs, it works almost as I want it, except that the hero never gets hit.
2. When choosing Magic or Run, the if statements do not display the echos, and goes to the TutorialError.

Note: %stat% is the hero's stat, while %estat% is the enemy's stat.

```
    :TutorialIntro
    title Tutorial^^!
    cls
    set /a ehealth=15
    set /a emana=15
    set /a ebstat=5
    set /a eostat=5
    set /a ecstat=5
    set /a elevel=1
    set /a health=15
    set /a mana=15
    set /a bstat=5
    set /a ostat=5
    set /a cstat=5
    set /a level=1
    echo You have run into a
    echo Level %elevel% Sock Puppet.
    echo -I made this from a combination of a sock, glue, and some paper.
    echo  If you lose to this thing, I'm not looking you in the eye again.
    echo  You know, if I could actually look at you in the first place. 
    echo.
    echo Level %level% Hero    
    echo %health% HP           
    echo %mana% MP             
    echo %bstat% Brawn                     
    echo %ostat% Obscurity    
    echo %cstat% Cowardice     
    pause
    goto Tutorial

    :Tutorial
    title Fight^^!
    cls
    if %ehealth% leq 0 goto TutorialWin
    if %health% leq 0 goto TutorialLoss
    echo Level %elevel% Sock Puppet. 
    echo (%ehealth% HP)
    echo.
    echo V.S.
    echo.
    echo Level %level% Hero
    echo %health% HP           
    echo %mana% MP             
    echo %bstat% Brawn                     
    echo %ostat% Obscurity    
    echo %cstat% Cowardice
    echo. 
    set /p answer= Fight(1), Magic(2), Run(3)     
    if %answer%==1 goto TutorialFight
    if %answer%==2 echo Sorry. You don't know magic yet.
    if %answer%==3 echo No. You are not going to run from a sock.
    goto TutorialError

    :TutorialFight
    set /a loss=0
    set /a eloss=0
    set /a num=%random% * ((%cstat%-%ecstat%) - 1 + 1) / 32768 + 1
    if %num% lss (%ecstat%/2) set /a loss=%random% * (%ebstat% - (%ebstat%/2) + 1) / 32768 + (%ebstat%)/2)                             
    if %num% geq (%ecstat%/2) set /a eloss=%random% * (%bstat% - (%bstat%/2) + 1) / 32768 + (%bstat%)/2)
    set /a health=(%health% - %loss%)
    set /a ehealth=(%ehealth% - %eloss%)
    goto Tutorial

    :TutorialError
    title Huh?
    cls
    echo Try that again. I believe in you. 
    pause
    goto Tutorial

    :TutorialWin
    title Victory
    cls
    echo Yay^^!
    echo Now I think you are ready for the big pond^^!  
    pause
    goto Intro

    :TutorialLoss
    title ...
    cls
    echo ...
    echo.
    echo Let's forget that ever happened.
    pause
    goto Menu
```

Comment: This not works: `if %num% lss (%ecstat%/2) ...`. You must calculate first the second number and use it in the if: `set /A num2=ecstat/2` & `if %num% lss %num2% ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional calculation:

```dos
Set/A halfecstat=ecstat / 2
```

Then change the line from:

```dos
if %num% lss (%ecstat%/2)
```

to:

```dos
If %num% Lss %halfecstat%
```

Also I've noted that the calculation which follows it has unbalanced parentheses so you may want to give that another careful look too.